# need to avoid callback is triggered when changing gpio modes

Tags: rpi.gpio

I have following code and I need to run it so, callback is not triggered when changing gpio mode from OUT to IN. Is this manageable with this library?

```
import pigpio, time

_gpin_a = 27
pi_gpio = pigpio.pi()


def _callback(channel, level, tick):
    #this callback is triggered always when mode is changed, need to avoid this
    print ("_callback called, level was {} at {}".format(level,tick))

pi_gpio.set_glitch_filter(_gpin_a, 500)
pi_gpio.set_mode(_gpin_a, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_gpio.set_pull_up_down(_gpin_a, pigpio.PUD_UP)
pi_gpio.callback(_gpin_a, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, _callback)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        while True:
            pi_gpio.set_mode(_gpin_a, pigpio.INPUT)
            time.sleep(.3)
            pi_gpio.set_mode(_gpin_a, pigpio.OUTPUT)
            time.sleep(.3)
            pass
```

Comment: Why would you need to change a pin mode?

Comment: set a flag when changing mode ... ignore the event when flag is set

Comment: `Why would you need to change a pin mode?` I need to send pulse and wait for answer on same pin

Comment: What are you connecting to that requires a pulse and sends an answer?

Comment: It is quite complex: I have a pin, that is INPUT mode and has HW switch connected. Based on the switch position, pin is grounded or it is in PUD_UP. Now the problem.. I need to control this pin both remote from web site and from the switch. If I want to change pin status remote, only option is to make it PUD_DOWN, which actually disables pin to react to HW switch events. So I am trying to swing pin modes to be able to react both website and switch. hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The callback will be triggered when the GPIO changes level.  There is nothing you can do to prevent that happening apart from disabling the callback.

Perhaps you need to look into why the GPIO level is changing and find a work around in your code.

Comment: OK, thanks for response. The code is complete as it is, so why level changes when changing modes? I havent find any info in doc ton that

Comment: Output mode drives the GPIO high or low against any external circuitry.  Input mode will weakly drive the GPIO high or low if pulls are enabled.  This is easily overridden by external circuitry.  If there are no pulls the external circuitry will determine the level.  If the external circuitry is weak the GPIO will float randomly between high and low.

Comment: OK I modified a bit the code adding initial mode as `pigpio.INPUT` and added pulls `pigpio.PUD_UP`. In case `pigpio.PUD_DOWN` was initially set, no callback is triggered when changing mode, however if `pigpio.PUD_UP` is set initially, then callback is called in every loop run. Can you explain in more details why ?